Footnote does not appear in the generated PDF file
When using Springer Nature’s LaTeX template and selecting the "[iicol]" formatting option, as requested by the Journal of Cluster Computing, the footnote associated with the title does not appear in the generated PDF file.
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num,iicol]{sn-jnl}
    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%% as per the requirement new theorem styles can be included as shown below
\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
%%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]% meant for sectionwise numbers
%% optional argument [theorem] produces theorem numbering sequence instead of independent numbers for Proposition
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 
%%\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}% to get separate numbers for theorem and proposition etc.

\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%

\sisetup{
    output-decimal-marker={,},
}

\raggedbottom
%%\unnumbered% uncomment this for unnumbered level heads

\begin{document}
    
    \title[Article Title]{Article Title\footnote{Some explanation about the title.}}
    
    \author{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}
    
    \abstract{The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. Authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to for word limits and if structural elements like subheadings, citations, or equations are permitted.}
    
    \keywords{keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, Keyword4}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}\label{sec1}
    
    The Introduction section, of referenced text \cite{bib1} expands on the background of the work (some overlap with the Abstract is acceptable). The introduction should not include subheadings.
    
\end{document}


